# Exception while parsing wsdl

Tags: java, exception, wsdl, nullpointerexception

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
WS-I: A problem occured while running the WS-I WSDL conformance check:
org.eclipse.wst.wsi.internal.analyzer.WSIAnalyzerException: null

  Nested exception is: 

  java.lang.NullPointerException
The WSDLAnalyzer was unable to validate the given WSDL File.
ChangedElements.wsdl    /wstest/WebContent/wsdl line 1  WSDL Problem
```

**Update:**

Netbeans gives this error:

```
cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'wsdl:definitions'. [7]
```

The part of wsdl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<wsdl:definitions   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/xxx/"
                    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                    name="xxx"
                    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/xxx/">
```

Comment: Two possibilities: The WSDL is invalid according to WS-I, or the tool you are using to validate it is broken. From the information you provided that's pretty much all I can think of.

Comment: @Darin I've updated question, you may want to recheck it. I think I can't post entire wsdl

Comment: what prevents you from posting the entire WSDL? How do you expect us verifying that this WSDL is valid without showing it?

Answer (score 3):

Look and vote at these bugs:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=323157
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=334057

EDIT: I have found the problem - but the solution got stuck somewhere in WTP team:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=323157#c7
- https://github.com/eclipse/webtools.webservices/pull/1

Answer (score 2):

Change the WSDL Definition to

```
                xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap"     
                xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/xxx" 
                xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="xxx" 
                targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/xxx">
```

note the Trailing Slashes being removed

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue and it appears to be mainly on referencing dotnet WCF and WSE services.

The only thing I have found to work is to build up the WSDL manually.